# Using a for loop to generate a 2 digit list of numbers less than or equal to 56, and whose sum is greater than 10

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a for loop to generate a list of numbers whose are less than or equal to 56, and then that have a sum greater than 10.

However my program displays 0 what am I missing?

This is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

int main()

{
    using namespace std;

    int x, sum;

    for (int i = 10; i <= 56; i++)
    {
        sum = (i / 10) + (i % 10);
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Comment: No, it prints [11](https://godbolt.org/z/zGe8qGYhn).

Comment: Sorry, yes I re ran it, how would I go about displaying the list of numbers less than or equal to 56 though?

Comment: Put the cout inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You print sum after the loop. So it prints the sum of last number in your loop. It is 56 and it prints 11 (5 + 6 == 11) not 0.

If you need to print the list of numbers with sum greater then 10 you need to check sum in loop and print number

```
int main()

{
    using namespace std;

    int x, sum;

    for (int i = 10; i <= 56; i++)
    {
        sum = (i / 10) + (i % 10);
        if(sum > 10)
        {
            cout << i << endl;
        }

    }
}
```